# How to copy files to a hidden folder

Tags: wine, copy, hidden-files

I want to copy a visible file to a hidden folder.

In this case, I want to copy a program folder to the

/.wine folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying to a hidden folder is the same as copying to a visible one, except that the folder name starts with a '.'

```
cp /path/to/file ~/.wine
```

If you want to copy a folder, don't forget to add "-r"

```
cp -r /path/to/folder .wine
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it didn't work before :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy files to hidden wine folder:

```
cp -r /path/to/folder/ /home/user/.wine/
```

If you want to move files to hidden wine folder:

```
mv -f /path/to/folder/* /home/user/.wine/
```